# Erro ao utilizar Mock: Wanted but not invoked: Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: java, junit, mock, mockito

Estou fazendo uma lista de exercícios e estou com dúvida no seguinte:

> Exercício 3 – O método verify, do pacote org.mockito.Mockito.verify, é
>   usado para checar a quantidade de vezes que um método é invocado.
>   Adicionar na classe ATest um teste para checar se ao invocar o método
>   area(2) o método pi() é invocado exatamente 1 vez.

A classe a ser testada é a seguinte:

```
package aula;

public abstract class A {
    public long fatorial(long n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        return n * fatorial(n - 1);
    }

    public abstract Object calc(Object x, Object y) throws 
    NullPointerException, Exception;

    public void msg(String txt) {
    }

    public double area(double r) {
        return 2 * pi() * r;

    }

    public double pi() {
        return Math.PI;
    }

    public double pow() {
        return pi() * pi();
    }

    public abstract int inc();
}
```

O teste que eu criei utilizando o JUnit 4 para resolver o exercício três é o seguinte:

```
@Test
public void test7() throws Exception {
    when(a.area(2)).thenReturn(2.0);
    //when(a.area(2.0)).thenCallRealMethod();
    verify(a, times(0)).pi();
    //assertSame(2.0, a.area(2));
    verify(a, times(1)).pi();
}
```

Como podemos ver, estou bem confusa com essa questão, pesquisei em muitas coisas e não consegui sanar minha dúvida. Quando tento rodar esse teste, o resultado é azul e não verde como esperado. Aparece o seguinte erro:

> Wanted but not invoked: Actually, there were zero interactions with
>   this mock.

Se alguém puder me me ajudar, explicando com a classe que disponibilizei ali em cima, eu agradeço! Eu realmente não estou conseguindo fazer ):

Comment: Ana, como você instancia no teste esta classe abstrata A?

Answer (score 5):

Você está verificando se o método `pi()` é chamado uma vez, porém você não chama ele em momento nenhum. É exatamente isso que o erro está dizendo:

> Wanted but not invoked: Actually, there were zero interactions with
>   this mock.
>
> Requerido, porém não invocado, não houve interações com esse mock.

O primeiro problema é que você ora diz que o método precisa ser chamado zero vezes:

```
verify(a, times(0)).pi();
```

E ora você diz que o método precisa ser chamado 1 vez:

```
verify(a, times(1)).pi();
```

Essa não é a raiz do problema, mas vai causar problema depois. Nesse caso, apenas o segundo `verify` é necessário.

Essa linha de código: `when(a.area(2)).thenReturn(2.0);` não está chamando o método. Você apenas está definindo qual deverá ser o comportamento do mock quando você chamar o método `area` passando o valor 2 como argumento.
Ou seja, quando você realizar essa chamada: `area(2)`, independente de qual seja a implementação do método `area`, o valor 2.0 será retornado. Se  você passar qualquer outro valor diferente de 2, o mock não fará nada, porque você não definiu qual deveria ser o comportamento para outros valores.

No seu caso, para que o seu verify funcione, você precisa chamar o método real, pois o método `pi()` é chamado no método real. Se você utilizar esse trecho de código `when(a.area(2)).thenReturn(2.0);`, quando o método `area(2)` for chamado, o método `pi()` nunca será chamado. O valor 2.0 será retornado imediatamente.

Seu método deveria ser implementado dessa forma:

```
@Test
public void test7() throws Exception {
    // Define o comportamento do mock. 
    //Nesse caso o mock deverá chamar o método real caso o valor dois seja passado como argumento. 
    when(a.area(2)).thenCallRealMethod(); 
    //chama o método a ser testado
    a.area(2);
    //Verifica se o método pi() foi chamado uma vez.
    verify(a, times(1)).pi();
}
```

Caso você queira que o verify funcione para qualquer valor passado como argumento, você pode implementar o método dessa forma:

```
@Test
public void test7() throws Exception {
    // Define o comportamento do mock. 
    //Nesse caso o mock deverá chamar o método real se qualquer valor Double for passado como argumento 
    when(a.area(any(Double.class))).thenCallRealMethod(); 
    //chama o método a ser testado
    a.area(5);
    //Verifica se o método pi() foi chamado uma vez.
    verify(a, times(1)).pi();
}
```